# Javascript validation of special characters in textbox and textarea

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to add validation to `textbox` and `textarea` to validate them against the following rules upon submit (ampersand and apostrophes are allowed). `//`,`./`,`/.`,`/*`,`*.`,`~`,`\\`

I tried the following code

```
alert("is valid "+ isValid("mhse sn hs ~"));

function isValid(value)
{
    return !/[~//./*././*\\]/i.test(value);
}
```

the above code will return false because `~` is in this code but if i try `/` this will return false so i think problem in grouping characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) write one javascript function which eliminates special charactors

```
  function isValid(str){

  var iChars = "#$%&"; // type your excepting keys here 
  var flag = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (iChars.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) != -1) {          
        flag = false;
    }
 }

return flag;
```

}

2) check your entered value with isValid() function like below

```
    isValid("hye!@#~%^&*)");
```

Answer:  if you entered special chars is there, then flag will returns false.

Answer (score 0):

when you escape, you do it carefully :D
for matching `*` or `.` literally, you need to escape them

the corrected version will be

```
/[~/\/\.\/\*\./\.\/\*\\]/.test(".");
```